# How to remove spaces in front of the second words in search result link?

Tags: arrays, pdo, php-7

I am trying to create dynamic searchable keywords for articles.
I am replacing spaces with + and generating links like google does example:
`search?q=text1+text2+text`
My code generate first link same as link in example, 
but adding + to in front of the second link like this:

> Fisrt Link (which is what I want):

`search?q=text1+text2+text`

> Second Link (Which is not right):

`search?q=+text1+text2+text`

Adding a + between `?q=+text`

> how can I remove that space from in front of the second keyword ?

I tried several ways but all did different things accept what I want.

Here is my code:

```
$keywords = "text1 text2 text3, text4 text5 text6";
$tag = explode(",",$keywords); 
for ($i=0; $i<count($tag);$i++){
    $cat = str_replace(" ", "+", $tag[$i]);
    echo "<a href=\"services/?q=".htmlspecialchars($cat)."\"><span itemprop=\"description\">".str_replace("+"," ", htmlspecialchars($cat))."</span></a>";
    echo "<span class=\"separator\">|</span>\n";
}
```

> I would like to generate all links like this:

`search?q=text1+text2+text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `trim` function removes spaces from the begin and end of a string.

Inserted into your not further changed code:

```
$keywords = "text1 text2 text3, text4 text5 text6";
$tag = explode(",",$keywords);
for ($i=0; $i<count($tag);$i++){
  $cat = str_replace(" ", "+", trim($tag[$i]));
  echo "<a href=\"services/?q=".htmlspecialchars($cat)."\"><span itemprop=\"description\">".str_replace("+"," ", htmlspecialchars($cat))."</span></a>";
  echo "<span class=\"separator\">|</span>\n";
}
```

Comment: @kaderkandar The evil tongues say PHP is useless at all. :)